# IE7 border extends beyond container width

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to setup a separating line in a container using a div.  [Here is the fiddle for the code](http://jsfiddle.net/dkindler/WtCPR/)

Works fine in all browsers except IE7 where the border is extending passed the right border area of the container div.  Tried many things.  Not sure what else to try.

By the way, if there is a better way using an HR or something else I am up for that but I like the way the div border line looks.  The line must extend to the left and right border of the container div.

Comment: Please always include the relevant code within your question.  External links are great but if they cease to exist, your question should still be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Add this class, then work perfectly in all the browsers.

```
.dividlineContainer
{
    width:308px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### A solution with negative margins?

How about the following:

```
.divideline {
  height:1px;
  line-height:1px;
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 8px -1.5em 8px -.75em;
}
```

I don't have access to a version of IE7 at the moment to test, but it should work. It works in everything that I have been able to test (FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari).

The reason why your original version would have been extending beyond the bounds in Internet Explorer is due to the difference between browsers when calculating a percentage width/height of a child when padding is applied to the parent element. The differences are down to each browser implementing a different 'Box Model'. For further reading about the subject checkout http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html or http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200612/internet_explorer_and_the_css_box_model/

```
.divideline {
  ...
  width:125%;
  ...
}
```

Also, using the +25% to take in to account your .75em padding would have caused problems if your elements involved ever changed width - because mixed measurements will only ever align at certain values.

### A better way

Rather than implementing a divide line that has to rely on negative margins to position correctly. It would be better to work with the way HTML naturally works, as aposed to against it. The following would make your life easier:

```
<div class="ccr">
  <div class="pad divide-after">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed 
     do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
     Ut enim ad minim veniam.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="pad">
    <p>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed 
     do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
     Ut enim ad minim veniam.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then:

```
.ccr {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 0 0 0 11px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.pad {
  padding: .75em;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.divide-after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

By applying your padding to a seperate non-dimensioned element, you automatically avoid the box model problem - because dimensions and padding are always calculated seperately. And by adding your divide to an existing wrapper means you cut down on markup.